# How to calculate the percentage of counts to condition in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to compute the percentage of some specific command - the equation below.
$$\frac{N(A=a\quad and\quad B=0)}{N(A=a)}$$

```py
id A B
0  a 0
1  b 1
2  c 0
3  a 1
4  a 1
```

Now I want to get these specific percentage:

```py
id A B  perc
0  a 0  0.3333
1  b 1  1.0
2  c 0  1.0
3  a 1  0.6666
```

**Furthermore**, I want this function where I can drop the rows by its percentage. For example, if the positives 1 and the negatives 0 are approximiately equal, I will drop these rows.

```py
id A B
 0 a 0
 1 a 1
 2 b 0
 3 b 0
 4 b 1
```

The result will be:

```py
id A B
 2 b 0
 3 b 0
 4 b 1
```

Comment: How is count `0.3333` from sample data?

Comment: Sorry for typing error. 1 row was not inputing.

Comment: What does mean `if the positives 1 and the negatives 0 are approximiately equal` ?

Comment: It means, for a sepcific `A=?`, the counts of `A=? and B=1` is equal to `A=? and B=0`.

Comment: OK, then my answer is understanding correct. Super!

Comment: Thanks, your answer do help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index(name='perc')
print (df)
   A  B      perc
0  a  1  0.666667
1  a  0  0.333333
2  b  1  1.000000
3  c  0  1.000000
```

For second solution remove values if same percentages by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), get values `A` by compare both columns and last filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with invert mask by `~`:

```
print (df)
   id  A  B
0   0  a  0
1   1  a  1
2   2  b  0
3   3  b  0
4   4  b  1

df1 = pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'], normalize='index')
print (df1)
B         0         1
A                    
a  0.500000  0.500000
b  0.666667  0.333333

idx = df1.index[df1[0].eq(df1[1])]
print (idx)
Index(['a'], dtype='object', name='A')

df = df[~df['A'].isin(idx)]
print (df)
   id  A  B
2   2  b  0
3   3  b  0
4   4  b  1
```